# Asus Google Nexus 7 [2012] + Android 5.1 + Windows 10 - Recovery Mode debugging fails

Tags: recovery-mode, nexus-7, 5.1-lollipop, usb-debugging

My configuration is in the title. I want to install custom ROM, but I can't access my device in Recovery Mode. I have ADB.

My tablet is usually visible by Windows:

1. Normal run - as "Android Composite ADB Interface". Android 5.0 is also aware that it's connected in debug mode, so everything works.
2. FastBoot menu, before I click "Recovery Mode" - "Android Bootloader Interface".
3. After I click "Recovery Mode" - device disappears. No device, not even "unknown device", in Windows' Device Manager. ADB shows nothing, obviously.

What I did:

- Enabled USB debugging and enabled for my specific PC (I had to boot normally and press "OK" on device).
- Disabled connecting as MTP and enabled as PTP (camera), as some good guys figured out here: [How do I get my Nexus 7 to show up in the adb devices list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48309/how-do-i-get-my-nexus-7-to-show-up-in-the-adb-devices-list)
- Tried restarting ADB server, re-plugging USB, etc.

Any ideas what's wrong? I've fought for hours with this. My only idea is that something's wrong with Android's permissions, but USB Debugging is active and MTP/PTP modes are configured properly...

Comment: A quick tip: Remove all the adb drivers installed using **[USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)** and freshly install **[15 seconds ADB installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118)**. Then try and reply

Comment: Thank you for the response. I haven't used USBDeview or anything similar. I actually did use "15 seconds ADB installer". I also tried to install http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top , but it was already installed. Later I also installed http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi , but I can't find where I got the link from. That's all I have in my download history, so that's all.

Comment: I'll refer you to one of my questions, see if this helps (it's a bit involved BTW): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123513/adb-sideload-doesnt-work-no-drivers